# Leaflet colorQuantile 'breaks' are not unique

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I work on some data with `shiny` and `leaflet` and run into a problem which seems to pop up here and there but I could not find a solution or implement the pieces I found

Lets use

`library(leaflet)`

`a <- c(5,4,1,1,2,1,1,1)`

vector `a` is a result of some filter in the app and can change. It works if the values are well distributed but in the above example it crashes the app when using following

`pal <- colorQuantile("YlGn", a, n = 5)`

And using

`pal(a)`

in

```
  leafletProxy("myMap", data = myData) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(data = theData,
                  fillColor = pal(a), 
                  fillOpacity = 0.8, 
                  color = "#BDBDC3", 
                  weight = 2,
                  popup = borough_popup)
```

with

> Error in cut.default(x, binsToUse, labels = FALSE, include.lowest =
> TRUE,  :    'breaks' are not unique

I found some [GitHub comments here](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/94) but struggle to implement it into a working solution.

I need some way to get around this problem as I cannot determined beforehand how much bins may work.

Answer (score -1):

Following the github example - did you try this?

```
quantileNum <- 5

probs <- seq(0, 1, length.out = quantileNum + 1)
bins <- quantile(a, probs, na.rm = TRUE, names = FALSE)

while (length(unique(bins)) != length(bins)) {
 quantileNum <- quantileNum - 1
 probs <- seq(0, 1, length.out = quantileNum + 1)
 bins <- quantile(a, probs, na.rm = TRUE, names = FALSE)
}

pal <- colorBin("YlGn", bins = bins)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I used above but end up with `pal(a)` putting everything as one color code. I assumed looking at the vector that I should have at least 2 bins and consequently 2 different colors?

Comment: `pal(a)
[1] "#F7FCB9" "#F7FCB9" "#F7FCB9" "#F7FCB9" "#F7FCB9" "#F7FCB9" "#F7FCB9" "#F7FCB9"`

Answer (score -1):

I've had to deal with this in a second-hand code I've inherited, though in mine it was colorBin being called after getting the quantiles beforehand.

I made it work by making a new function by copying colorBin's source code with the only change being replacing the cut() with .bincode() (and removing its label = FALSE argument). Quantiles with the same floor will receive the same colour, and I haven't run into any issue since.